# linux: where's the "real" segmentation fault handler?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault

If I read/write/jump to an ummapped address ie.

```
.text
    .global _start
_start:
     movl   $1,%edx
     jmp     *%edx
```

this causes a segmentation fault.

I wonder, what's the actual part of the system (kernel)
that intercepts reads/writes to unmapped addresses (how ?) 
and throws the "user mode" signal ?

Comment: Well there's hardware support for the how, perhaps http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/cpu-rings-privilege-and-protection For the where, I guess you should look for the interrupt handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything flows from the architectures trap table. This is usually called entry.S (split on x86 between entry_32 and entry_64.S) and has assembler linkage that does a number of things (depending on config) before heading into the C code of the kernel proper.

So an invalid memory access should enter through either page_fault or general_protection and will probably end up doing force_sig_info before finally being queued back to user space in send_signal (kernel/signal.c).

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented for different architecture. 
For example, on x86, you can check the source at:

```
do_page_fault: linux/arch/x86/mm/fault.c
```

Comment: Page faults and segmentation faults are completely different things.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPC chips that are not "Book E" (e.g., recent chips for embedded systems), a segmentation fault starts with an exception 0x300 (for data) or 0x400 (for instructions.)  The user/supervisor mode flag is set to supervisor, the MMU is turned off, and the CPU jumps to address 0x300 or 0x400, giving control to the operating system.